# Making a dynamic form in angular, add fields on runtime

Tags: angular, formbuilder, dynamic-forms

I am making a site where I can create exams with multiple choice questions. I have a html page in which I can add questions to an exam.

A question consists out of the description of the question and multiple options. An option contains the response and a value to check if the response is true or false.

The user should be able to add options to the question when filling in the form. I am trying to use formbuilder, formgroup and formarray for this but it is not working. When I press add option, a new response and a new valid field should appear.

[image: form]

The fields are appearing on my html page, but I get this error when filling in the form. "Cannot find control with name response" +"cannot find control with name valid"

This is the HTML page:

```
    <form [formGroup]="questionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(questionForm.value)">
        <div>
          <label>Description:</label>
          <br />
          <input class="form-control" id="description" type="text" formControlName="description">
          <br />
          <label>Options</label>

          <div *ngFor="let test of arrayOptions; let i = index">
            <div class=mx-4>
              <label>Response</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="response" type="text" formControlName="response">
              <label>Valid</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="valid" type="text" formControlName="valid">
            </div>


          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn-block-option text-primary" (click)="addOption()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add option
          </button>


        </div>
        <div class="block-content block-content-full block-content-sm bg-body-light font-size-sm">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

This is my ts page:

```
    export class AddQuestionComponent implements OnInit {

      questionForm;
      arrayOptions;

      constructor(
        private examSimulatorService: ExamSimulatorService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
      ) {
        this.questionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          description: '',
          options: ''
        })
      }
      removeOption(i) {
        this.questionForm.removeControl(i);
      }
      addOption() {

    this.questionForm.addControl(this.questionForm.controls.options.value, 
    this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            response: "",
            valid: ""
          }
        )]));
        this.arrayOptions.push(this.questionForm.controls.options.value);
      } 

      onSubmit(questionData) {
        this.examSimulatorService.addQuestion(questionData);
        this.questionForm.reset();
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.arrayOptions = [];
        this.addOption();
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell the exact errors without a running sample.

Some things I have noticed:

1) When we are using a `FormArray` we have to bind it in the template via `formArrayName`

2) I don't really get why you are calling `addControl` on the questionForm. Should'nt we push a new option to the `FormArray`?

Example form with a `FormArray`:

```js
this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
  question: ["Sample Question"],
  options: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      response: ["Response Example"],
      valid: [true]
    })
  ])
});
```

Referencing the `FormArray` in the template via `formArrayName`:

```
<form [formGroup]="questionForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="question" />

  <div formArrayName="options">

    <div *ngFor="let option of options.controls; let i=index">
      <b>Option {{i}}:</b>
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="text" formControlName="response" />
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="valid" />
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Finally the method for adding a new option:

```
addOption() {
  this.options.push(
    this.fb.group({
      response: [""],
      valid: [false]
    })
  );
}

// getter which simplifies the access via 'this.options' used in the addOption method
get options() {
  return this.myForm.get("options") as FormArray;
}
```

Take a look at the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-array-4x1l4). Feel free to fork and edit it so that it shows your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't added formArray and formGroup in your html

HTML Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="questionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(questionForm.value)">
<div>
   <label>Description:</label>
   <br />
   <input class="form-control" id="description" type="text" formControlName="description">
   <br />
   <label>Options</label>
   <div formArrayName="options">
      <div *ngFor="let test of arrayOptions; let i = index">
         <div class=mx-4 [formGroupName]="i">
            <label>Response</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="response" type="text" formControlName="response">
            <label>Valid</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="valid" type="text" formControlName="valid">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" class="btn-block-option text-primary" (click)="addOption()">
   <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add option
   </button>
</div>
<div class="block-content block-content-full block-content-sm bg-body-light font-size-sm">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Component :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  questionForm;
  arrayOptions;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.questionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      description: "",
      options: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrayOptions = [];
    this.addOption();
  }

  removeOption(i) {
    this.questionForm.removeControl(i);
  }

  addOption() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.questionForm.get("options");
    const newGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      response: "",
      valid: ""
    });
    control.push(newGroup);
    this.arrayOptions.push(this.questionForm.controls.options.value);
  }

  onSubmit(questionData) {
    console.log(questionData);
  }
}
```

[*Find the code here*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjqhl8)